# Using Geocoder to show user's location Address

Tags: android

I have this method to show the user's latitude and longitude on a map activity:

```
public void animateMap(Location location){
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

       Toast.makeText(MyMapActivity.this,
                "Sie sind an\n" + lat + "\n" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        mapController.animateTo(point, new Message());
        mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);

    }
```

How to implement the Geocoder on my method? So the Toast will display the location's address instead of the coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use

```
 Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
List<Address> myList= myLocation.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
Address add = myList.get(0);
String addressString = add.getAddressLine(0);
String country = add.getCountryName();                      
String city = add.getLocality();
```

Comment: It gives error when GeoCoder couldn't find the location from the give lat lon. and application will forced closed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest implementation is by using the geocoder class:

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH); 
        geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        List<Address> ls=new ArrayList();
        ls= geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        String myLocation = ls.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
```

You can check all the information returned by this class and choose which one fits you most. It contains from country names to landmarks name, neighbors postalcodes... almost anything you may need.

But keep in mind, if Google has no info about this location will return a null string!

So for you exapmple should be something like that:

```
public void animateMap(Location location){
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();


String myLocation;
 try{
           Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);   
        geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        List<Address> ls=new ArrayList();
        ls= geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        myLocation = ls.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
 }catch(Exception e){
     myLocation="Sorry, we have no information about this location";
 }



   Toast.makeText(MyMapActivity.this,
            "Sie sind an\n" + myLocation , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    mapController.animateTo(point, new Message());
    mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);

}
```

Comment: too bad, I got null for myLocation. Any solution?

Comment: the subadminarea is a very detailed info you can try the adminarea etc etc so you can have at least some basic inoframtion for this location!

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of Addresses at your location from Geocoder and check for a [null or empty result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html):

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext,Locale.getDefault()); 
 List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, long, 1);
 String myLocation = "";
 if(address != null && !address.isEmpty())
 {
    myLocation = address.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
 }
```